# SQL Join of multiple tables by single column without duplicates and fill up other columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have twelve tables (for twelve months) that have same columns (Contract_number, Days, etc...).
Whan I need is to select all entries from column Contract_number for all twelve months, and than have 12 columns with days from each table.

Table January

```
 Contract Number # Days
 1                 10
 2                 20
```

Table February

```
 Contract Number # Days
 1                 20
 2                 40
 3                 10
```

Table March

```
 Contract Number # Days
 2                 50
 3                 70
 4                 5
```

Output table should look like this

```
 Contract Number # Days January # Days February # Days March
 1                   10             20              NULL
 2                   20             40               50
 3                  NULL            10               70 
 4                  NULL           NULL              5
```

I have tried with this query, however I get three columns with Contract_Number

```
 SELECT dbo.[January].*, dbo.[February].*, dbo.[March].*
FROM dbo.[January]
    FULL JOIN dbo.[February]
        ON dbo.[February].CONTRACT_NUMBER = dbo.[January].CONTRACT_NUMBER
    FULL JOIN dbo.[March]
        ON dbo.[March].CONTRACT_NUMBER = dbo.[February].CONTRACT_NUMBER
```

I have tried searching all join questions here, but none of them actually covers such scenario.

Comment: Separate tables for each month = a generally bad idea.  Consider maintaining a single table, with a date column to differentiate each month.

Comment: And wait until you have to change years

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: You mean looks like MSSQL instead

Comment: Agree, unfortunately data is already in database in this way. I can easily append these tables and make one with date distincter, but still I can't get the view from the question above.

Comment: You are getting three columns with contract_number because you are including them in your `select` by using `tableName.*`.  Use `tableName.columnName` instead.

Comment: Create a view which UNION ALL those tables. Use that view until you can fix the db design properly.

Comment: @JenR when I select only tablename.columname from only one table then I get NULL for fields that are populated in other tables but not in table that I selected column from.

Comment: `COALESCE(january.contractName, february.contractName, march.contractName, [etc adding the rest]) as ContractName` - that will grab the first non-null value and use it.  Even better, join in a table that has all the contractNames and use that as the source for the ContractName column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a horrible database design.  All the data should be in a single table, with an additional column for the month (or better yet, date).

That said, your approach will work, but you need to be more explicit with the columns:

```
SELECT COALESCE(j.CONTRACT_NUMBER, f.CONTRACT_NUMBER, m.CONTRACT_NUMBER) as CONTRACT_NUMBER,
       j.days as jan, f.days as feb, m.days as mar
FROM dbo.[January] j FULL JOIN
     dbo.[February] f
     ON f.CONTRACT_NUMBER = j.CONTRACT_NUMBER FULL JOIN
     dbo.[March] m
     ON m.CONTRACT_NUMBER IN (f.CONTRACT_NUMBER, j.CONTRACT_NUMBER);
```

Note that this introduces table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: both yours and Juan Carlos solution do as I asked, however I get different number of rows for your and his solution (yours return smaller number) so I need to check why there is a difference.

Comment: @azdralovic . . . I fixed the logic, which should resolve the issue.  My purpose in answering was to show that `full join` can work.  Aggregation is a very sensible approach.

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/IOCPZ95594)**

```
With data as (
    SELECT 'January' as Month, [Contract_Number], [Days] 
    FROM January
    Union ALL
    SELECT 'February' as Month, [Contract_Number], [Days] 
    FROM February
    Union ALL
    SELECT 'March' as Month, [Contract_Number], [Days] 
    FROM March
)
SELECT [Contract_Number],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'January' THEN [Days] END) as January,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'February' THEN [Days] END) as February,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'March' THEN [Days] END) as March
FROM data
GROUP BY [Contract_Number]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]